# Hitting Dynamic Endpoint in Websphere 7.0

Tags: java, https, websphere, websphere-7

I have a Dynamic Endpoint setup in Websphere 7.0. The intention is for the Dynamic Endpoint to capture outbound HTTPS requests from the application and implement some Mutual SSL logic.

My question is this. In my application code, do I need to do anything to hook into the Dynamic Endpoint? Or does it suffice to make a HTTPS request direct from my code and that will be intercepted by the Websphere Dynamic Endpoint (based on the URL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure an outbound dynamic endpoint for websphere, for each outbound connection attempted, this association is checked ahead of the SSL configuration scope association. In specific scenarios like connecting to a third party server we may need separate SSL configuration, Please refer [IBM Journal](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_birk/0612_birk.html). Once the endpoint is created all HTTPS requests for the selection start to use the endpoint. SO you need not do any code change in application apart from hitting HTTPS URL. Hope this answers your question.